# fpga multiplexor - select line controlled by a soft processor

Tags: fpga, multiplexer, nios-ii

I have 5 pins coming into an FPGA (inputs). I have two different sets of 5 output pins. I want to select which set of output pins that I connect the input pins to. What kind of multiplexer is this called?

I have a soft processor running on th fpga which will call the select line to the multiplexer.

In verilog, what would this look like

```
module switch (inputs, outputs1, outputs2);

    input [4:0] inputs;             
    output [4:0] outputs1;          
    output [4:0] outputs2;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

This is demultiplexing, not multiplexing. You're routing fewer paths into more, not more paths into fewer.

You don't say if the pins without the input routed to them will (a) be tri-state or (b) be at a fixed level.

The circuit for (a) would connect inputs to both outputs, then use the mux control to enable the tri-state drivers on the two output sets. One set would be enabled while the other set was disabled.

The circuit for (b) would connect the each input to output set 1 through a logic gate, with the same done for output set 2. The mux control would switch the logic gates to a fixed level on one set while letting the other set flow through. OR gates would let the unused output set be driven high, AND gates let it be driven low, or you could produce some other pattern.

Comment: Hi @TonyM, thanks for you helpful response. The 5 signals are JTAG signals being routed to two separate devices. So the input pins consist of `(4 inputs NRESET, TCKC, TDI, TMSC)` and 1 output `(TDO)`. So would I use option (a) or (b)?

Comment: Hi @duttom, you'd have to edit your question with a decent schematic (not a link to one) for me to comment on that, depends on existing pull-ups. The schematic drawing tool is dead easy to use. And one of pins is muxed after all. Can you see why it being JTAG should have been written in the original question?